# What is the difference between ELB and ALB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

I would like to know where ELB and ALB are routed? What layer is it? I had this question while an interview and couldn't answer it. If you can help me it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

hello,

everything is covered in this awesome article: https://www.sumologic.com/blog/aws-elb-alb/

Tell me if you have more specific questions